# Bringing my Haitian wife and little boy to the UK

Tags: united-kingdom, immigration, family

I desperately need advice!  I am married to a Haitian woman, we have a 10-month-old son. We have been married for exactly 1 year, and have known each other for nearly 5 years.

Currently, I spend approximately 11 months of the year in Haiti,and one month at home, where I have a house which is paid for.  I work in Haiti for The Haitiano American Institute.  However, the salaries here are extremely low, $800.00, but good, relative to the cost of living. I have savings of £47,000.00 in a UK bank.

I need to get my family out of Haiti; it is incredibly dangerous here for non-blacks, kidnaps are not infrequent, and we worry for our son's safety.  My wife and I want better for our boy and we want to return to the UK as a family.

How can I get my family to the UK? My wife has a Haitian passport, and I'm going to apply for a UK passport for my son. In addition, I have a medical issue which requires treatment in the UK. I can document this, along with the documents related to my relationship and son's birth.

Comment: Does it have to be the UK, or would elsewhere in the EU work? And if the UK-only, what job will you be getting in the UK to support the family?

Comment: The financial requirements can be met partly or completely through cash savings, not just income. See (https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/525708/Appendix_FM_1_7_Financial_Requirement.pdf), section 7.2.4.

Comment: Further to Gagravarr's comment: the EU rules governing family immigration are far easier to meet than the UK rules, but as a British citizen returning to the UK from outside the EU, you will have to use the UK rules.  In particular, you do not have to meet any financial hurdles to move together to another EU country, such as Ireland or France.  (Furthermore, once you've lived in that country for at least six months, you can move to the UK under the EU regulations, because of the Surinder Singh case.  Search this site for *Surinder Singh* to learn more.)